# Reading attribute of XML declaration in C#

Tags: xml

I got an XML file with following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?libxml version="1.0"?>
<Lib>
....
</Lib>
```

I am using XMLDocument and need to read the version of libxml....
how should i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeking a processing instruction (a node with a question mark at the beginning of the XML tag), so use this:

```
System.Xml.XmlProcessingInstruction instruction = 
  doc.SelectSingleNode("processing-instruction('libxml')") as System.Xml.XmlProcessingInstruction;
string result = instruction.Data;
```

result will contain **version="1.0"**